# Trying to understand the filter is not working

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am kind of stumped why the below filter is not working. I am getting the stream value in the input topic as 'start'. Any ideas why this simple is not working? 
I am using Spring Cloud stream 3.0, spring boot 2.2.1.RELEASE on Java 11.

> Code snippet

```
        public Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> filterstream() {
            return input -> input.map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(key, value))
                    .peek((key, value) -> System.out.println("......Key :" + key + "....Value: " + value))
                    .filter((key, value) -> value.equalsIgnoreCase("start"))
                    .peek((key, value) -> System.out.println(".after filter.....Key :" + key + "....Value: " + value));
       }
```

> application.yml

```
filterstream-in-0:
          destination: myinput
        filterstream-out-0:
          destination: filteredoutput
```

Comment: Not sure what's not working. Do you mean you are not seeing any filtering that takes place? Not sure why. Need more information.

Comment: yes, I am not seeing any filtering. I just tried with value.contains("start") and its working. So it looks like something to do with string format, perhaps?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case. It is possible that the text that you are sending to the input topic is corrupted with possible extra characters.